# How to display all numbers only in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to display all numeric only in oracle sql?

Example:

```
12345
abcdef
6789
123abc
abc1234
987
```

Result:

```
12345
6789
987
```

Tried this syntax but it doesn’t work:

```
WHERE ID_No like '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be using reverse logic through `REGEXP_LIKE()` function with `'[^0-9]'` pattern

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ID_No, '[^0-9]')
```

**or**

with `[:digit:]` posix as `[^[:digit:]]` pattern

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ID_No, '[^[:digit:]]')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1e6c12bed8aee3bc243c3f9f42142e01)</kbd>

Comment: Tried this in Hue Hive it doesn’t work. There’s no REGEXP_LIKE function...

Comment: Sorry, we are sharing the data in Oracle Sql Bench but it’s having a downtime issue, someone told me that they have the same syntaxes. Once the sql bench is up I’ll try REGEXP_LIKE...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest solution uses standard (non-regular-expression) functions.

```
select *
from   t
where  translate(id_no, '~0123456789', '~') is null
;
```

Note the use of an additional character (I used `~` but you could use any other non-digit character) - this is needed due to Oracle's bizarre specification of `TRANSLATE` when the third argument is `null`.

`translate` will replace every digit with "nothing" (meaning, it will remove them all), while replacing tilde with itself and leaving all other characters untouched. So, the return value is `null` only if all the characters were digits.

Equivalent solution:

```
...
where ltrim(id_no, '0123456789') is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use REGEXP_LIKE() function:

```
select * from tablename
where REGEXP_LIKE(ID_No, '^[0-9]+$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, if you are on oracle 12.2 or higher, is to use `TO_NUMBER` with `conversion error` clause as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE TO_NUMBER(ID_NO DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR) <> - 1
    OR ID_NO = '-1'
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Tejash in Hue Hive there’s no REGEXP_LIKE only extract and replace...